# Array question for two different outcomes i.e. positive or negative

Tags: c, arrays

I wish to write a program where the user inputs a value between -50 and 50.I do not know how to repeat the sequence in the numbers. Also two outcomes are shown but only one input can be given one at a time.

```
Enter a value from -50 to 50: 5
1
22
333
4444
55555
Enter a value from -50 to 50: -5
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

Comment: would you clarify what do you mean by repeat the sequence? and please exactly state what is your desired input and output format.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter a value from -50 to 50: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = -n; i >= 1; --i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        printf("%d", i);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a value from -50 to 50:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num>0)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                printf("%d",j);
            }
        printf("\n");       
        }
    }
    else
    {
        num=num*-1;
        for(int i=num;i>0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                printf("%d",j);
            }
        printf("\n");       
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output with positive input :**

```
Enter a value from -50 to 50:8
1
12        
123        
1234                                                                                                              
12345                                                                                                                        
123456                                                                                                                       
1234567                                                                                                                      
12345678
```

**Output with negative input :**

```
Enter a value from -50 to 50:-5                                                                                              
12345                                                                                                                        
1234                                                                                                                         
123                                                                                                                          
12                                                                                                                           
1
```